# Java setTimeZone changing date

Tags: java, timezone

I'm parsing a String "11/15/2020" into a date. I need to set the time zone to EDT but this changes date to 11/14/2020. I'm assuming because I'm in CST it's removing that hour time difference from : Sun Nov 15 00:00:00 CST 2020 and this becomes the prior day.

I would like to set the timezone without modifying the date. How can I go about doing this? It would not be sufficient to just add an hour.

```
dateFormat dataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
dataFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Constants.EDT_TZN));
```

Comment: Oh yes, the good old, no, the bad old `Date` class. It plays such tricks on you. The `TimeZone` class has design flaws too, and `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously horrible. Do yourself a great favour, don’t use those classes. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For a date without time zone (so it stays the same date in all time zones) you need the `LocalDate` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A date has no time zone

> I would like to set the timezone without modifying the date.

A date-only value such as November 15 of 2020 has no notion of time zone. You have no need to worry about time zones.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, or `Calendar`.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL.]

## `LocalDate`

In Java, a date-only value without time-of-day and without time-of-day is represented by the `LocalDate` class.

```
String input = "11/15/2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/lg2kSJ).

> ld.toString: 2020-11-15

## Moment

Perhaps you do want a moment rather than just a date. I assume that would mean you want the first moment of the day.

Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means the day may start at a time such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* determine what a particular day in a particular time zone begins.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST`, `EDT`, `CST`, or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). For example, `CST` could be China Standard Time just as easily as Central Standard Time in the Americas.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2020-11-15T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

Generally best to store and exchange moments in UTC. To adjust from our specified time zone to UTC, extract a `Instant` from the `ZonedDateTime`. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2020-11-15T05:00:00Z

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

> instant.toString(): 2020-11-15T05:00:00Z

## Convert

If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Look to new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes.

The legacy class `Date`, though misnamed, is equivalent to `Instant`, both representing a moment in UTC. `Instant` uses a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

```
Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;
```

Be aware that the **`Date::toString` method tells a lie**, applying the current default time zone. While well-intentioned, in practice this is quite confusing. One of many reasons to avoid this class.

Answer (score 1):

Time in Java (as per the Date object and System.currentTimeMillis) is defined as the milliseconds past January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. All setting the TimeZone does is localize the offset in hours at a specific (Java) time.

So you have three choices:

1. Don't add the extra hour and set the the timezone to EST, in which case you get a new date.
2. Add the extra hour in which case the date will stay the same
3. Find or build your own time/date package